# How to set @HTML.EditorFor to readonly using JQuery in an ASP.NET MVC View

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

What is the way to set an HTML.EditFor to readonly by using JQuery in an ASP.NET MVC view? I am able to set it manually with the following:

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PurchasingAgent, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control ", @readonly = "readonly", @id = "id-PurchasingAgent" } })
```

But when I try using the following JQuery it does not work:

```
 $('#id-PurchasingAgent').attr('readonly', readonly);
```

I get an error in the Chrome browser that says readonly is undefined as shown below:

[image]

Is there a way to set an Html.EditorFor to readonly using JQuery?
The comment below to use the following JQuery solves my problem:

```
$('#id-PurchasingAgent').attr('readonly', true);
```

Comment: `$('#id').prop('readonly', true);` or  `.attr('readonly', true);`

Comment: The error states 'readonly' is not defined, thus it already points out that it is not defined or may be out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

try with this, where TTT is the ID as a selector for jquery

```
$("#TTT").attr("readonly","readonly");
```

Click [here](https://drive.google.com/uc?id=10mmOX8jtwkhBEAt5TgNLezay7mYrbXlH) to see Demo